# JavaScript Remove() The last input appended onto the dom

Tags: javascript, append, appendchild, removechild

I have a form that places a user's inputs onto the dom as well as removing them. But the problem is that the remove() function is removing the first input which was placed onto the dom first. I'm trying to figure out how to remove the last input appended onto the dom. please help :)

```js
// Delete From The Dom.
const delBtn = document.querySelector('.del-btn');

delBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Remove Form Input.
  let h6_w = document.getElementById('h6_weight');
 
    h6_w.remove();
});


// Add User's input To The Dom.
const addDom = document.querySelector('.add-dom');
const wForm = document.querySelector('.weight-form');
  
wForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

   // Get Input Value.
   const value = wForm.querySelector('input[type="number"]').value;
   const value1 = wForm.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;

   // Create Elements.
   const h6_weight = document.createElement('h6');

   // Adding Id.
   h6_weight.setAttribute('id','h6_weight');

   // Add Content.
   h6_weight.textContent = value + value1;

   // Append To Dom.
   addDom.appendChild(h6_weight);
   
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the duplicated id of dom elements. You need to set the `id` of each element differently.

Or you can set the same class to each new element for querying the last element.

```
...
// Remove Form Input.
let h6_w_elements = document.querySelector('.h6_weight_class');
h6_w_elements[h6_w_elements.length - 1].remove();
...

// Add User's input To The Dom.
...
// Adding Id.
h6_weight.classList.add('h6_weight_class');
...
```

Comment: thanks for the help :)  I'm getting an error. I've attempted h6_w_elements.remove() and that works fine but when adding [h6_w_elements.length - 1] its throwing app.js:208 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (app.js:208) on the line h6_w_elements[h6_w_elements.length - 1].remove() would you know why that is ?

Comment: Well, you need to replace querySelector to `querySelectorAll`. If that helps, please mark as an answer to help me ;)

Comment: If the inputs is empty and I press the delete button it's throwing an error is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you assign one `id` to multiple elements. You should replace it with the `class` attribute because the id value must be unique within the HTML document. [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp).

To choose last element of certain class you can use:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
const lastElement = elements[elements.length - 1];
```